# Hovering title inside a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I have a question about something I have build for my website.

[image]

Above is a gif of me highlighting titles on my web landing page. As you can see, the line extends further than the text. I think I have an idea about why it is doing this, because I have a row which is equally spaced into three parts. I have tried altering the code and I cannot get it to go past the lines, however.

```
        <div class="icons">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="img-responsive animated bounceInUp" href=""><p class="effect-underline" style="font-family: Ubuntu; font-size: 60px;">About Me</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="img-responsive animated bounceInUp" href=""><p class="effect-underline" style="font-family: Ubuntu; font-size: 60px;">My Projects</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="img-responsive animated bounceInUp" href=""><p class="effect-underline" style="font-family: Ubuntu; font-size: 60px;">Contact Me</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Above is the code I use to display the three columns to divide it up and also equally space and align the text. Is there any possible way which I could prevent the underline feature going further than the text, while maintaining this column structure?

This is the CSS associated with the `:hover`.

```
     p.effect-underline:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 1em;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 2px solid;
     margin-top: 10px;
     opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);
    }

    p.effect-underline:hover:after {
      opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
```

Comment: We can't tell anything without the associated CSS.

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, I wouldn't think that the CSS would matter in this situation. As it is more in relation to the html, however I will update that now.

Comment: The line must come from somewhere...it certainly won't be in the HTML.

Comment: I've updated the post now.

Comment: Well the `p` would be 100% wide as it's block level..so that would be it...right? Make the paragraph `inline-block`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I already coded the p to have a width of 100% in the CSS, if that is what you're relating to.

Comment: But you don't want the paragraph to be 100% wide..do you? You only want it to be as wide as the text,

Comment: Ah I see... I have already made the paragraph an inline-block format?

Comment: wrap text in `span` and apply `effect-underline` class to it directly.

Comment: ..then remove the 100% width on the paragraph and that should solve it.

Comment: After removing the 100% width on the paragraph, it is no longer displaying any kind of underline animation now.

Comment: This is why we ask for a working demo...otherwise we're working in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `p` as `display:inline-block`, and because you are setting `position: absolute` in pseudo-element `::after` you need to set `position: relative` in `p`

Avoid using inline styles, try style in CSS instead.

```css
p::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}
p:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row icons">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="img-responsive animated bounceInUp" href="">
        <p class="effect-underline" style="">About Me</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="img-responsive animated bounceInUp" href="">
        <p class="effect-underline">My Projects</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="img-responsive animated bounceInUp" href="">
        <p class="effect-underline">Contact Me</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.